# Relative path in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, path, relative-path, tilde

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Make Games with Scirra Software</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Game making with Construct." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="game maker, game builder, html5, create games, games creator" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/default.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/plugins/coin-slider/coin-slider-styles.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="~/images/favicon_apple.png" />
    <script src="~/js/googleAnalytics.js"></script>
</head>
```

Renders as:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Make Games with Scirra Software</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Game making with Construct." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="game maker, game builder, html5, create games, games creator" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/default.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../plugins/coin-slider/coin-slider-styles.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../images/favicon_apple.png" />
    <script src="~/js/googleAnalytics.js"></script>
</head>
```

Why is the JavaScript URL `~/` and not `../`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Strange implementation indeed, but unfortunately that is the way ASP.NET handles this. Here is what I do to compensate:

```
<script src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/js/googleAnalytics.js")%>"></script>
```

Comment: You probably only need ResolveUrl(), as ResolveClientUrl creates the whole URL, rather than just the relative path.

Comment: Thanks, ive tried every single combination of this stuff, but the best it resolves to is: <script src="/ScirraNew/js/googleAnalytics.js"></script>.  My site is in the ScirraNew folder, but it needs to resolve to ../js/Googleanalytics.js!

Comment: <link id="Link1" runat="server" href="~/js/googleAnalytics.js" /> this works fine, but renders as a link tag, sigh :(

Comment: @Tom Gullen - Are you sure you are using `ResolveClientUrl` (not `ResolveUrl`).  The believe the former creates the ../ style path, whereas the later creates a root-relative path.  I am going to test right now to be sure though.